# How to remove the interpolation between 2 frames for a specific object using the Python API?

Tags: python, animation, bezier-curves, interpolation

I want to render the results of a molecular dynamics simulation in Blender using the Python API.

I have managed to load the data and animate the molecules. Sometimes a molecule moves from one side of the box to the other due to the presence of periodic boundary conditions; however, because of the interpolation between frames, the molecule goes through the whole system in the animation, which is not realistic: it should just pop up on the other side.

[image: Anomalous movement of the molecules]

The code I'm using to build the animation is more or less like this:

```
# Iterate over the trajectory
for n in Trajectory:

    # Create a new frame in the animation
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set( n )

    # Iterate over all the Bezier curves
    for i in range( len( Mol_object ) ):

        # Iterate over the coordinates of the points of the curve in the n-th frame
        for k, coords in enumerate( Mol_coords[n][i] ):

            # Define the new coordinates of the point
            Mol_object[i].data.splines[0].bezier_points[k].co = coords

            # Add the point to the last frame
            Mol_object[i].data.splines[0].bezier_points[k].keyframe_insert(data_path="co", index=-1)
```

where `Trajectory` is a list of frames for the animation; `Mol_object` is a list containing the objects associated to each molecule (Bezier curves), and `Mol_coords` a dictionary with the frame as key and the values are the list of coordinates for each point of the curve at that time.

Is it possible to remove the interpolation between the frames where the molecule jumps, but just in these and for the specific molecule? Thanks in advance!